# Floating element to the left causes unexpected resizing of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why does removing the "float:left" from an element make the bounding box suddenly increase in size? Ideally, I would expect that wherever the elements are floated inside the box, the size would remain consistent.

UPDATE: I've included detailed images which show both the problem & the expected behavior. I've also pasted the CSS & HTML involved in the following paste-bin:

http://pastebin.com/bYMQR98p

In real life, you can still see the issue at the link below (which will remain online for a good time to come). Just remove the "float:left" from the element "pag pag-inner":

http://www.axonnsays.com/page/2/

Images with the issue:

Correct (with "float:left" removed)

[image]

Broken (with "float:left" present)

[image]

Comment: floating elements dont stretch parents, unless there is `clear` after them

Comment: When you unfloat your item, the div `.pag` gains a `padding-bottom:30px;`

Comment: Off topic, but I think the phrase "the likes of Facebook" may be cause for confusion.

Comment: You are taking one element out of float (*out of its floated siblings*). So, that will cause a newline. The `padding` of the `ul` will now take effect and hence you are seeing that increase in size. What do you really want to do?

Comment: @Abhitalks I wanted to have the second page look like the first page, where the padding is visible. I think I will remove the padding altogether but the inconsistency was driving me nuts! The issue does not happen on the first page, but then again that first page has a very different HTML :(. I'm not very happy with the coding of this theme.  I am also  obviously very far behind on my CSS lessons :(.

Comment: @ether What ".pag" div are you referring to? :). There is no such div. And I do not see any new such style being added to any of the elements when I unfloat it. I used both Firefox and Chrome to inspect the styles and the padding-bottom 30px is always there, regardless if that element is floated or unfloated. Even if it were like you say: is that a rule of CSS that when you unfloat something, some other element should automagically gain new properties? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put float:left in your ul class="pag pag-inner".

Comment: Wow. It worked :). Thank you SO much!!! You have no idea what headache this has been! Can you explain your answer a bit?

Comment: Or as the comments say, you can remove the `padding:bottom:30px` from it.